# llama2 running pytorch produces a "failed to create process"

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, anaconda, llama

## CONTEXT

1. I am trying to run llama2 on my local machine.
2. I have followed the documentation available on the github repository

https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama

**thank you in advance for your support**

## what did I do?

1. install anaconda
2. clone the llama repository

https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama

3. download the models
4. create a virtual environment named llama2
5. install pytorch on Anaconda

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

6. install local components

`pip install -e .`

7. executed the following command line

```
torchrun 
--nproc_per_node 1 example_text_completion.py 
--ckpt_dir llama-2-7b-chat/
--tokenizer_path tokenizer.model 
--max_seq_len 512 --max_batch_size 6
```

## the error

`failed to create process.`

Comment: Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: @FlyingTeller this was the complete error message.

I have found the issue. I'll close the error and share the answer.

thank you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## root cause

the error comes from an incorrect-or-missing update of the torchrun-script.py

## how to correct the issue

1. edit the file

`C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\[YOUR ENVIRONMENT]\Scripts\torchrun-script.py`

2. replace the first line with

`#!c:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\[YOUR ENVIRONMENT]\python.exe`

3. save the file

voilà, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Location for **torchrun-script.py** in Windows 11 for me was -

```
C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\environmentname\Scripts\torchrun-script.py
```

I updated the line 1 of **torchrun-script.py** to following -

```
#!C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\environmentname\python.exe
```